# Is there a cv.ROTATE_NONE?

Tags: python, opencv

I know that OpenCV has three rotations:

```
ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE
ROTATE_180
ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE
```

Is there also a no-op rotation like `ROTATE_NONE`?

I'd prefer using that over having an `if`-statement.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it, the [`RotateFlags` enum](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/1db1422fbdc1a03d1523b50ad9b05d72cbd39616/modules/core/include/opencv2/core.hpp#L1123) only contains those 3

Comment: there isn't. If you are not afraid of unnecessary function calls (because you want to call rotate function in the case you don't want to rotate at all) you can encapsulate the opencv rotation in your own function that calls opencv rotation if rotation code is one of ROTATE_90/_180/_CLOCKWISE or exits (assigning src to dst) if your personal "ROTATE_NONE" code is given.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, you've cited all three existing rotations as specified in [the official documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga6f45d55c0b1cc9d97f5353a7c8a7aac2). They are the only ones checked for in the [source for the rotate function](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/fc810434de47171c309ecc2cd06ff98bb39b1237/modules/core/src/matrix_transform.cpp#L860).

I was curious whether you could devise a hacky solution anyways, and you can! Disclaimer: you definitely should **not** be using the following, as it relies on the representation of enum values and uses pretty un-pythonic syntax.

The idea is to call `cv2.rotate(in, rot_code, out)` and abuse the fact that `out` [isn't modified](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/fc810434de47171c309ecc2cd06ff98bb39b1237/modules/core/src/matrix_transform.cpp#L877) if `rot_code` isn't a valid flag.

```py
import cv2

ROTATE_NONE = -1 #  some value not associated with one of the existing flags

img = cv2.imread("img.png")
img_rot = img
# img_rot will contain the rotated image if you
# pass a valid rotation flag, and the original image otherwise
cv2.rotate(img, ROTATE_NONE, img_rot)
```

Comment: Why give an example of something you should definitely not use?

Comment: I believe there's value in understanding how something could be achieved and why it's a bad idea.